# The webpage has a redirect loop in my chrome browser

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller

I'm trying to  make a custom login form and redirect the user to a student page if he has the ROLE_USER.

Controller:
        public class LoginController {
        @Autowired 
        private UserService userService;

```
    @RequestMapping("/student")
    public String mypage(Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("TADADAGHDGHA");
        return "student/student";
    }     
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
//    public String logoutPage() {
//        return "/logoutPage";
//   }     
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login/loginPage";
    }           
}
```

spring-security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">       
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="ROLE_USER" />         
        <form-login login-processing-url="/login" login-page="/login/loginPage"
            username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"
            default-target-url="/student" authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?auth=fail" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logoutPage" />  

    </http>
```

In VIEWS folder I have a page logout,a folder named LOGIN with login.jsp and tiles-definitions.xml and another one named STUDENT with student.jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't restrict the permissions to view your login page. Otherwise people will be continually redirected to a page they don't have access to... This is where your redirect loop is coming from.

Also, there may be an issue with your `authentication-failure-url` setting. It doesn't seem like a valid link per the given configuration.

Answer (score 0):

According to spring documentation you can check if a user has a role in your spring-security.xml this way:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login/*" method="GET" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> OR
<intercept-url pattern="/login/*" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

If the user has the role, only then he can view the page.

You can also restrict method access of your service layer this way;

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public void methodName() {
   // Only users with ROLE_USER can access this content.
}
```

You can use permissions if you want for more information refer to Spring Documentation, Spring in Action or any Spring book.